# How to block syscall with ptrace on ARM?

Tags: c, linux

I have used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12016223/2536878.

And is working on x86.

I have tried this code on ARM phone and is not working (syscalls are wrong).

I guess ORIG_EAX is invalid for ARM so what value use instead of ORIG_EAX?

Now I have this code (works on x86):

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int i;
        pid_t child;
        int status;
        long orig_eax;
        int kill_ret = 0;
    char c[100];

        child = fork();

        if(child == 0)
        {
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
        execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);
        }
        else
        {
                i = 0;
                while(1)
                {
                        wait(&status);
                        if (WIFEXITED(status) || WIFSIGNALED(status) )
                                break;

                        orig_eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, child, 4 * ORIG_EAX, NULL);
                        if (orig_eax == 2)
                        {
                                fprintf(stderr, "Got it\n");
                                kill_ret = kill(child, SIGKILL);
                                if (kill_ret == -1)
                                {
                                    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to kill ---> %s\n", strerror(errno));
                                }
                        }
                        printf("%d time, system call %ld\n", i++, orig_eax);
                        syscall_prompt: 
            printf("Allow syscall? Y/N: ");
            fflush(stdout);
            read(0, c, 100);
            if(c[0] != 'Y' && c[0] != 'N') {printf("\n"); goto syscall_prompt;}
            if(c[0] == 'N') { kill_ret = kill(child, SIGKILL); if(kill_ret < 0) { fprintf(stderr, "Cannot kill child\n"); } exit(1); }
            ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, child, NULL, NULL);
                }
        }
    printf("return\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use r7 register for getting system call number, and r0 register for return value of the system call.

[image]

[For details refer here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html)

Comment: I'd still like to know (as I think the OP), how can I find the constant for it for the `ptrace` syscall?